# My git bash terminal is not giving me any output after any command or anything

Tags: git, terminal, git-bash, no-response

[This is my git bash terminal ,Here i was trying to change my admin password, but nothing seems to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNGYo.png)

I was in the virtural enviorment and my command 'python manage.py runserver' was executed then i pressed ctrl+c to break since i forgot the password, then i entered 'python manage.py changepassword' the there is no output from the terminal, to which i thought that i can enter my new password '1234' and confirm it by retyping it but nothing seems to happen. The git bash terminal is not responding to any input. Please help me out. What can i do?

Comment: What is manage.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not finish the process correctly.
You can see in the runserver line that there is no $ in front.
Try to press CTRL + C or CTRL + Z several times in a row. The simplest way would be to restart the terminal.